# defaultValue in ListPreference, using different languages

Tags: java, android, android-preferences, listpreference

I wanted to initialize a defaultValue for my ListPreference view. Here's my code:

```
<ListPreference
    android:key="list_days"
    android:title="@string/game_length"
    android:defaultValue="??"
    android:summary="@string/game_length_summary"
    android:entryValues="@array/game_duration"
    android:entries="@array/game_duration" />
```

Where the question marks are I wanted to put some default value inside. My array/game_duration looks like this:

```
<resources>
<string-array name="game_duration">
    <item name="1">1 day</item>
    <item name="10">2 days</item>
    <item name="30">3 days</item>
    <item name="90">4 days</item>
    <item name="365">5 days</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

and in german:

```
<resources>
<string-array name="game_duration">
    <item name="1">1 Tag</item>
    <item name="10">2 Tage</item>
    <item name="30">3 Tage</item>
    <item name="90">4 Tage</item>
    <item name="365">5 Tage</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

Now, when I wanted to have the 3 days as default value, what should I type inside the

```
android:defaultValue=""?
```

I can't put in "3 days", because I'd get the problem, that the default value won't work on other languages. The same with "3 Tage".

Is there some other way like, choosing the 3rd item out of the array? I mean then I'd get the language independent item.

Any suggestions? I'd like to set the defaultValue to the 3rd item of the array.

Comment: This thread got answered by using "300" as value but mine got also text

Comment: because you need to separate between the entries and the entryValues, have 2 arrays